# I can't solve (Could not build the my application for the simulator.) flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, ios-simulator

Yesterday,  i update my macbook to macOS Mouterey and then update Xcode
and then when open Android Studio i run my app in flutter
i get this error :

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            5.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A32C7DF-2445-4177-9C26-584684610C84, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
    xxxx/myproject/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1:1: error: unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner")
   xxxx/myproject/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1:1: error: unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner")
   xxxx/myproject/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1:1: error: unable to open file (in target "Runner" in project "Runner")

    warning: Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
```

Comment: Have you tried Flutter Clean? And Also What is Output of Flutter doctor?

Comment: YES , I try run flutter clean , and also the Output of flutter doctor its ok

Answer (score 0):

in your xcode you have to change your compatibility to 9 th generation or lower since u are using iphone 12[image: check here]... check the image

Comment: ok , i change to Xcode 10 , 11 , and 13 , it no working

Comment: no, just change the project format...

Comment: yes ، I mean project format , like your image

Comment: what did you change it to ?

Comment: I change project format to Xcode 10-compatible

Comment: put it to like the image.. or less

Comment: i put like image , it no working

Comment: is it showing thesame error?

Comment: yes , i did copy my code , and creat another new project , thank u